# Create Custom AlertDialog requestFeature exception

Tags: java, android, exception, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to create my own custom AlertDialog in a DialogFragment for a simple alarm clock application, and the code for the onCreateDialog method is below.

```
public class CreateAlarmSetting extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener, AlertDialog.OnClickListener, TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener, NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener {

    /*
    the isEdit variable is set to true when an existing alarm time is clicked, this will add the
    "delete" button to the dialog, to possibly delete the item from the listview
     */
    private boolean isEdit = false;
    public static final String ISEDIT_PARAM = "isEdit";
    public static final String ALARMSETTING_PARAM = "AlarmSetting";
    public AlarmSetting alarmSetting;

    private TimePicker timePicker;
    private NumberPicker numberPicker;
    //private Button cancelButton, createButton, deleteButton;
    //View of the dialog layout that will be inflated
    private View main;
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public CreateAlarmSetting() {

    }

    /*
    Below are a few of the Fragment lifecycle methods
     */

    public void setArguments(Bundle bundle) {
        isEdit = bundle.getBoolean(ISEDIT_PARAM);
        alarmSetting = (AlarmSetting) bundle.get(ALARMSETTING_PARAM);

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getActivity().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /*
        Not doing anything yet, because findViewById() doesn't work at this point in the lifecycle
         */

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //    TODO: check if this is to edit a current alarmSetting and add the save button and delete button


        main = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_alarm_setting, null);
        //Initialize views and their listeners
        timePicker = (TimePicker) main.findViewById(R.id.alarm_fragment_dialog_timepicker);
        numberPicker = (NumberPicker) main.findViewById(R.id.alarm_fragment_dialog_numberpicker);
        //    cancelButton = (Button)  main.findViewById(R.id.alarm_fragment_dialog_cancel_button);
        //  createButton = (Button)  main.findViewById(R.id.alarm_fragment_dialog_create_button);
        timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(this);
        numberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(this);
        //cancelButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        //createButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        numberPicker.setMaxValue(45);
        numberPicker.setMinValue(0);
        //create display based on given parameters
  /*
        if (isEdit) {
         //   ViewGroup parent= (ViewGroup) main.findViewById(R.id.alarm_fragment_dialog_button_container);
            deleteButton= (Button) main.findViewById(R.id.alarm_fragment_dialog_delete_button);
            deleteButton.setText("Delete");
            deleteButton.getLayoutParams().height= LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            deleteButton.getLayoutParams().width= LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            deleteButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            createButton.setText("Save");

//TODO: Set Display Settings to current alarm settings, includes having cancel, delete, save buttons
            timePicker.setCurrentHour(alarmSetting.getHours());
            timePicker.setCurrentMinute(alarmSetting.getMinutes());



            //Replace create button with the save add the delete button
            ViewGroup parent= (ViewGroup) main.findViewById(R.id.alarm_fragment_dialog_button_container);
            ViewGroup v=(ViewGroup) edit.findViewById(R.id.miscellaneous_items_container);
            //v.removeView(edit.findViewById(R.id.alarm_fragment_dialog_delete_button));
            parent.addView(edit.findViewById(R.id.alarm_fragment_dialog_delete_button), 1);
            //Replace create button with save button
            parent = (ViewGroup) createButton.getParent();
            int index = parent.indexOfChild(createButton);
            parent.removeView(createButton);
            parent.addView(parent.findViewById(R.id.alarm_fragment_dialog_save_button), index);


        }*/

        return main;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        if (main == null) {
            main = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_alarm_setting, null);
        }

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setView(main);
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", this);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Create", this);
        builder.setTitle("Create a new Alarm Setting");
        AlertDialog alertDialog=builder.create();

        //show or create?
      return  alertDialog;


    }


    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /*
    Below are listeners for the actions in the dialog
     */
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:


            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL:


            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:

        }


    }


    @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int val, int num) {
        //Do something

    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker picker, int hours, int minutes) {
        if (alarmSetting != null) {
            alarmSetting.setHours(hours);
            alarmSetting.setMinutes(minutes);
        } else alarmSetting = new AlarmSetting(hours, minutes, false);


    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //do stuff for each button
        switch (v.getId()) {


        }


    }
```

When I run this code in the emulator, I receive an exception saying

```
    01-22 20:32:39.489    1883-1883/com.stanfordude.ryan.snooze E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:215)
        at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:234)
        at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:336)
        at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:351)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:256)
        at android.app.DialogFragment.onStart(DialogFragment.java:490)
        at android.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1570)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:863)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How do I fix this?

Btw, sorry for my messy code and comments, I'm new to java

Comment: add complete code and logcat

Answer (score 0):

Its not the code as I can see from the error, its the requestWindowsFeature or something you have called before setContentView on the top. You should call the request before setting the contentView like this :

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Hiding title bar using code
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    // Hiding status bar using code
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: In a fragment, the requestWindowFeature method is only available through the getActivity() method which returns null at that point in the lifecycle.

Comment: Is it possible for us to see the whole code so I can debug ?